# python kwargs: how to use best as a filter for objects?

Tags: python, optimization, keyword-argument

I want to use arguments that are passed to my function as `**kwargs` like a filter. That is, only if the attributes of object `n` are `== v` the element should be appended to the list.

My current solution looks like this. Is there better way to do this? Looks pretty hacky to me.

```
def filter_nodes(self, **kwargs):
    r = []
    for n in self.pcode:
        for k,v in kwargs.iteritems():
            if getattr(n,k) == v:
                sign  = True
            else:
                sign = False
        if sign is True:
            r.append(n)
    return r
```

**Update**

This is what the function now looks like. Thanks for all the useful comments.

```
def filter_nodes(self, **kwargs):
    bib = {'eq': '==','gt': '>','st': '<','geqt': '>=','seqt': '<=', 'neq':'!=' } 
    r = [] 
    for n in d:
        if all(eval('%s%s%s' % (getattr(n,k),bib[v[1]], v[0])) for k,v in kwargs.iteritems()):
            r.append(n)
     return r
```

Comment: I guess that the `getattr` can raise an `AttributeError` if you call `filter_node(nonexisting_attribute = 666)`. Is that intended?

Comment: That is indeed intended, yes.

Comment: In your code whether `n` is appended depends only on whether the last `getattr(n,k) == v` for items in keywords is true. Since dictionaries aren't ordered, it'll effectively be random. Doesn't sound useful.

Comment: Ehhhm, you are absolutely right. Makes it pretty much worthless.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe this will have the same functionality:

```
def filter_nodes(self, **kwargs):
    return [n for n in self.pcode 
            if all(getattr(n, k) == v for k, v in kwargs.iteritems())]
```

**UPDATE**: actually, it won't, it will require all the attributes to be equal with the values found in kwargs, whereas in your snippet, the last key/value pair of kwargs will decide if n can be added or not. perhaps you should specify in which exact conditions it is allowed to be added.

Comment: The requirement that all the attributes have to be equal with the values found in kwargs, is what I am after. Nice solution.